# Find first item inside angular brackets after occurrence of other item, using RegEx, in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, regex

I have an xml-like text, in which I would like to find the item that occurs in the first occurrence of a certain pattern:
typically:

```
...
<PropertyGroup><name>true</name></PropertyGroup><PropertyGroup>....
....
```

Could also be

```
...
<PropertyGroup>
<name>
true</name>
</PropertyGroup>
...
<PropertyGroup>
...
```

In the above, I need to extract the "name".

My initial assumption was that all occurrences were to be in one line, and I wrote my code using string properties, but it is very difficult o take in consideration every possibility, and only RegEx can save me.

I just don't know how to write it...

I Have started with something like this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("(?<=<PropertyGroup>#)<+");
Match matches = regex.Matches(Text)[0];
MessageBox.Show(matches.ToString());
```

I think this finds the first item after a `<PropertyGroup>`, but I don't know how to make it get the item within the angular brackets... (which may be after one or more newlines, and/or spaces).

I know that there are utilities for parsing xml, but I am looking for something simple to insert in a c# program

Can someone please help me ? Thank you very much.

Edit:
Actual file content (the one I am testing now, with no weird spaces):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets">
    <Import xxx/>   
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup><myProp>true</myProp></PropertyGroup><PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros"/>
  <PropertyGroup/>
<!--maybe other stuff -->  
</Project>
```

Comment: Regex will not save you but instead end up throwing you into a much deeper in darker pit than you already think you are in. You should rather use an XML parser. You say "xml-like text". Do you mean "XML text" by that? If so, using LINQ for instance, is "something simple to insert in a C# program"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LINQ to XML is really quite simple and is much more reliable than using regular expressions:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

...

```
XElement xmlTree = XElement.Load(fileName);
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003";

List<XElement> properties = (
    from propertyGroup in xmlTree.Descendants(ns + "PropertyGroup")
    from property in propertyGroup.Elements()
    select property
).ToList();
```

Now `properties` should contain all the `XElement` objects for the immediate children of all `PropertyGroup` elements. You can that get both their names and values with:

```
foreach(var property in properties)
{
    string name = property.Name.LocalName;
    string value = property.Value;
    // process both strings   
}
```

This way you do not have to worry about any kind of whitespace and it is a very maintainable and extensible solution to go on and retrieve other information from the XML.

Plus, it is really something generally worth reading up on and [here is the place to start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx). This will not be the last time you need to handle an XML file, and you will be glad if you do not always have to figure out a regex to parse (which, let me repeat that, is not even generally possible).

Comment: This seems really nice and flexible, but I can't get it to give me any items... When I added a check for properties.Count == 0 -> there is nothing loaded. Even when I removed the second line (the filter for Elements), still nothing - so I don't find any "PropertyGroup" items ?

Comment: @Mihaela It worked for me. Have a look whether your `xmlTree` is correctly loaded.

Comment: The xmlTree seems to contain only the surrounding tag <Project> and the next item, and it stops before the <PropertyGroup> tag... even though the <Project> is not closed. What is worse, its value seems to be a combination of the items below...

Comment: @Mihaela is your xml maybe malformed?

Comment: It is actually a Visual Studio property sheet - all property sheets seem to read like that... and Visual Studio would complain (not load projects) if it was malformed.

Comment: @Mihaela huh, that is very odd then. I will try to use this on a property sheet myself.

Comment: @Mihaela in fact, would you be able to show us the actual contents of your file? maybe upload them [here](http://pastebin.com/) and add the link to your question

Comment: @Mihaela fixed it. The problem was that your XML file uses a namespace, while my test file didn't. For that to work properly, you create an `XNamespace` variable and prepend that to every element name (in this case only `PropertyGroup`). Check out the code in my answer again and it should work like a charm. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(?s)<PropertyGroup>\s+<([^>]+)
```

Example:

```
var result = 
    Regex.Match(input, @"(?s)<PropertyGroup>\s+<([^>]+)")
    .Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: FYI, the `(?s)` isn't necessary.  It turns on Singleline mode, which enables the `.` (dot) to match linefeeds.  There are no dots in your regex, so Singleline mode is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

"I know that there are utilities for parsing xml" No, not so much utilities as classes built right into the .net framework.

Suggest you readup on [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx)